# Wordpress Grabity form gform_after_submission

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, pardot

I have a form and i want to send the data to a third party location via endpoint and gform_after_submission.
my form was working fine, but now its not after adding a new field in the third party location (pardot).
this is my old form handlder that i used to use to send the data to Pardot:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
$post_url = $_POST['input_9'];
$body = array(
    'First Name' => $_POST['input_1'],
    'Last Name' =>$_POST['input_2'],
    'email' => $_POST['input_3'],
    'Zip' =>$_POST['input_4'],
    'Company' =>$_POST['input_5'],
    'Phone' => $_POST['input_6']
);
```

now on my thirdparty form we added a Radio button; i added that radion on my gravity form and i need to add it to the code above, i tried that but appearently its not working since i guess gravity form radio button is somehow an array...
so can you please help me with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i found the solution:

```
$body = array(
'First Name' => $_POST['input_1'],
'Last Name' =>$_POST['input_2'],
'email' => $_POST['input_3'],
'Zip' =>$_POST['input_4'],
'Company' =>$_POST['input_5'],
'Phone' => $_POST['input_6']
 'distant-field-name' => $_POST['field-input-name']
```

);